# Fragment add not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm getting the 'The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, WeatherFragment)' error.

This is my current code, I'm already using the android.support.v4.app.Fragment import, so what could be the problem?

Here's my currently code and the imports I'm doing:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class WheaterActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wheater);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new WeatherFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First guess off the top of my head is that WeatherFragment does not extend from android.support.v4.app.Fragment but instead extends android.app.Fragment. Check you import statements in WeatherFragment.java.

Comment: Such an easy thing to notice... guess I'm too I'm already used to the code that I can't see such a thing. Thanks a lot!